# can't figure out embed for discord

Tags: php, wordpress, discord

So i have a Wordpress site built with a php template... and when i paste link on discord it show default embed preview .. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75gm1.jpg)
is there a way i can get twiiter card like this for discord [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmSXM.jpg)

i tried to add meta tags on header.php also on function.php but can't really figure out how to achieve that.

Comment: According to https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/82p8i6/a_basic_tutorial_on_how_to_get_the_most_out_of/, they read the same basic OG meta tags, as Facebook does.